# Comparing datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return a "YES" in a new column if a datetime in another column is after a given datetime, in this case, July 1 of this year.

```
source_df['Request Date']
0      2018-03-16 16:29:18
1      2019-05-07 17:40:16
2      2019-06-03 12:35:18
3      PENDING
```

```py
df['Requested in Time?'] = source_df['Request Date'].apply(lambda x: "YES" if x.str[0:8] > datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1) else "NO")
```

This gives me the error message `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'str'`.

However, when I modify my code to read `x > datetime.datetime` I get this error message: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'`

So it seems to be thinking of my `source_df` data as both datetime and float?

I also realize I need to deal with PENDING (which should also return "YES") but one thing at a time.

Comment: pandas can keep time as float value  - timestamp - so you may have to get `datetime.datetime` as `timestamp` OR try `x.dt >  datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

See [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) for an overview of pandas date and time functionality.

```
def check_request_date(x):
    try:
        return 'YES' if pd.to_datetime(x[:10]) > pd.to_datetime('2019-07-01') else 'NO'
    except:
        return 'YES' if x == 'PENDING' else 'UNKNOWN'

df['Requested in Time?'] = df['Request Date'].apply(check_request_date)
```

Result (according to your example code, in reality YES/NO probably should be just the other way round, i.e. YES if request date <= deadline):

```
          Request Date Requested in Time?
0  2018-03-16 16:29:18                 NO
1  2019-05-07 17:40:16                 NO
2  2019-06-03 12:35:18                 NO
3              PENDING                YES
```

---

If you want to have a more flexible function with the deadline passed in as argument:

```
def check_request_date(x, deadline):
    try:
        return 'YES' if pd.to_datetime(x[:10]) > pd.to_datetime(deadline) else 'NO'
    except:
        return 'YES' if x == 'PENDING' else 'UNKNOWN'

df['Requested in Time?'] = df['Request Date'].apply(check_request_date, args=('2019-07-01',))
```

(Please pay attention to the comma after '2019-07-01' to make it into a tuple)

---

Alternative: `pd.to_datetime(x).date() > datetime.date(2019,7,1)` using the [date](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html) function.